# Error while creating query with date criteria

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, schema

I have created a data-grid box from access table containing columns as below :

```
SELECT 
    ID, [Size in mg], [Die head number], [Inspection Date], 
    [Next Calibration Date], [Die size in microns], 
    [Condition of DIE-1], [Condition of DIE-2], [Condition of DIE-3], 
    [Condition of DIE-4], [Condition of DIE-5], [Condition of DIE-6], 
    [Condition of DIE-7], Observations, Inspector 
FROM 
    MSdies
```

But when I tried to create a query shown below, I get an error:

> The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query

```
SELECT        
    ID, [Size in mg], [Die head number], [Inspection Date], 
    [Next Calibration Date], [Die size in microns] 
FROM 
    MSdies  
WHERE 
    ([Die head number] < NOW())
```

Please guide me how to solve this

Comment: What’s the type of the [Die head number] you’re comparing to Now()?

Comment: Sorry The i made an error while rewriting SQL here actually the compared field is  [Next Calibration Date] and of date type and the error is as mentioned above

Comment: are you using SQL?

Comment: Are you able to show the actual vb.net code where your calling this query from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a typed DataSet but have failed to mention it. If so then every table adapter is associated with a DataTable and that DataTable has a schema that matches the original query in the table adapter, which is usually basically a `SELECT *` on a database table. Any query you add to that table adapter must produce the same schema or it cannot be used to populate that DataTable. If you want a query with a different schema, e.g. only some of the columns in a table, then you need to create a new DataTable and table adapter for that schema.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems you are using SQL. write this :

```
 SELECT        
        ID, [Size in mg], [Die head number], [Inspection Date], 
        [Next Calibration Date], [Die size in microns] 
    FROM 
        MSdies  
    WHERE 
        ([Die head number] < GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the same count and types of fields, so try:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, [Size in mg], [Die head number], [Inspection Date], 
    [Next Calibration Date], [Die size in microns], 
    [Condition of DIE-1], [Condition of DIE-2], [Condition of DIE-3], 
    [Condition of DIE-4], [Condition of DIE-5], [Condition of DIE-6], 
    [Condition of DIE-7], Observations, Inspector 
FROM 
    MSdies
WHERE
    [Inspection Date] < Date()
```